# C++ WinAPI 'AnimateWindow' has not been declared

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to make a WinAPI C++ program however I am running into the following errors:

```
error: 'AW_SHOW' was not declared in this scope
error: 'AW_HIDE' was not declared in this scope
error: 'AW_BLEND' was not declared in this scope
error: 'AnimateWindow' was not declared in this scope
error: 'SW_MINIMISE' was not declared in this scope
```

I have tried using ::AnimateWindow however I recieve the same error.
This is my header file, included before windows.h

```
#ifdef WINVER
#undef WINVER
#endif

#ifdef _WIN32_WINNT
#undef _WIN32_WINNT
#endif

#define WINVER 0x0500
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
```

I have also tried setting the vars to 0x0502, and commenting out the preprocessor in Winuser.h for AnimateWindow.

Comment: Are you including WinUser.h directly? Don't do that. Include Windows.h.

Comment: Roger, no I am including windows.h directly. Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: Is the project defining `NOGDI` or `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`?  You need to check the makefile as well as source files, since macros can be set on the command-line.

Comment: Also, what version of the Windows SDK are you using?

Comment: Thanks guys, have found issue (see question). Many thanks for your responses!

Comment: @Shane: Make sure to answer your own question so this question can be closed as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have figured it out.

The file in which the error was occurring was being included in my main.cpp, however it was included after windows.h in main.cpp.

Comment: I will, however I must wait 12 hours.